# Is there a way to dynamically hide sheets in Excel without Visual Basic?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to hide certain sheets in excel depending on a value in a cell. For example, I want it to show sheets 1-31 if the cell is 'January' and so on for all the months. I can't use VBA at this point in time. I have tried looking for how to do this, but all I can find are ways to do it with VBA, is it even possible to do it without?

So far I have tried custom views, but I don't think that they work for hiding sheets, just rows and columns. I tried to set up links to all of my sheets and hiding them all but you can't access hidden sheets with a link.

Comment: You can't do it without VBA unless you do it manually using the keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Looks like there is a JavaScript-based way in newer office versions (see the `Automate` tab)
https://www.howtoexcel.org/hide-sheets/ (I haven't tried it so I don't know if it can be adapted for your purposes)

Answer (score 1):

This would have to be done using VBA. Or you would need to use some other program that can alter excel using another coding language. But that would force more requirements for your end users.